# Backbone router: how to wait for the views to be ready?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

On a mapping application organized using Backbone, the main view displays paths on a map. This view needs data that it fetches from the server on first load, which takes time (~500ms).

Each path has a unique url set up with routes/navigate.

When a user clicks on an external link of this url and arrives on the application, the map view can't display the path immediately; it needs to fetch the data first.

I have set up a quite complex/convoluted process in order to do this (described below) but am wondering if there's a better/canonical way to do this?

---

Here's my solution so far:

1. In general

   - there is a global "View" called "dispatch" that is not really a view, but is used to store the state of the various other views
   - when ready, the map view triggers an event to dispatch, so that it knows that the map is ready ("mapIsReady")
2. Upon loading a new url

   - on a new url, the route object updates the model immediately, and then triggers an event to dispatch, saying in essence "update the path when possible"
   - upon receiving this message, dispatch monitors the state of the map view (that it stores itself) using setTimeout
   - when the map view is ready, dispatch triggers the "update" event on the model, that tells every view to show it

Advantages

- it works!
- views don't call each other's methods directly, everything is done via events

Limits

- the dispatch "view" is really not a view at all
- the chain of events can be a little complex to follow... and to debug in the future
- setTimeout doesn't feel right

---

Edit: or maybe my problem is that I want to synchronize everything on the page and I shouldn't. On the page there are three views that render the same information in a different way, and only the map view has the problem of needing data for rendering.

So it's the map view's problem and not everyone's else's, and so maybe the correct approach is to have all this dispatch business happen inside the map view, and let the other views do their job as soon as they can...?

Comment: If you put some code it will be more clear.

Comment: Your map view is fetching data from some where ok? is it from a third party? you are calling that method. (may be REST) through model.. you can use success and error call back functions for it. So when the map data fetch returns success you can handle after that in success call back. or if error handle it in error call back

Answer (score 0):

It is not bad to create separate object to manage complex logic across multiple view. But It is not necessary to make it view. You can use plain JS object as some kind of Controller/Mediator.

Also I think it is better to use promises in this case (for example [$.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)). They make much more easier to control async logic in application, for example you can do something like:

```
$.when(prepareMapView, loadPathData).done(showPathToView);
```

Comment: The use of promises wouldn't be a bad idea, except that mapView needs to be prepared just once, while it may show many paths (the one read from the url, and then other paths following user inuput). So yes, for the first path from the url, we could chain it following the preparation of the map, but in that specific case we would need to filter out the general "sync" event that tells the map view to do the rendering. Using flags, while somewhat inelegant, is a more generic approach IMHO.

Comment: Constraint  that mapView needs to be prepared just once is easy to solve using promise. You should just cached created promise and return it from `prepareMapView` method. So first time you create promise, store and return it and do your async preparation and next times you just return stored promise (resolved or not).

Answer (score 0):

### Yo may use like this:

```
this.yourMapModel.fetch({
  success: function(model, response, options){
      //"your code after successful return from url"
  },error:function(model, response, options){
       //"your code after error"
});
```